# Increase defaults axis labels R plot

Tags: r, plot

I got a data frame with the repetitions of an action on one minute intervals (if it is 0 it jumps that minute)
something like this:

```
    timestamp          count
 2015-01-07 01:15:00     2
 2015-01-07 01:16:00     1
 2015-01-07 01:18:00     1
 2015-01-07 01:20:00     3
 2015-01-07 01:25:00     1
 2015-01-07 01:26:00     2
```

When I try to plot, it only used 5 labels on the plot (x axis)
like this:

[image]

What I want is to simply increase this to 10 labels on the x axis.

This data is variable so I can't use *axis at*

So, is there a way to tell R to set 10 labels instead of 5?

This is the code I use, df is a data frame as show above

```
 X <- zoo(df$count, order.by=as.POSIXct(as.character(df[,1])))
 plot(X, main="Repetitions", sub="", xlab="Time of the Action", ylab="Number of Actions")
```

Comment: sure you can use axis at. you can also use par settings `plot(x <- 1:10, xaxp = c(range(x), 10))`

Comment: Please provide the code you used to make your plot so that we can give a relevant answer

Comment: xaxp = c(range(x), 10)) this did not work ;(
it keep showing only 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `axis.POSIXct` to add the axis and `pretty` to choose 10 tick marks for the `at` argument. Note that the plot function does not add the x axis (`xaxt="n"`). I also reduced the size of the labels with `cex.axis=0.7` to make the 10 fit.

```
library(zoo)
y.POSIXct <- ISOdatetime(2015, 01, 1:24, 1:24, 24, 24)
y <- zoo(rnorm(5), y.POSIXct)
plot(y, xaxt="n")
axis.POSIXct(1,index(y), at=pretty(index(y), n = 10), cex.axis=0.7)
```

[image: 10 labels]

Comment: This works, it certainly increase the tick marks, although there is a strange behaviour. Meaning it does not increase the tick marks to 10, it kind of depends of the data I think... 
For me with n=10 gives me 7 tick marks and when I set it to 11 it gives me 15 tick marks, for you with n=10 it gives you 11 tick marks
Thanks anyway this would do the trick